# guava version conflict with HBase 1 and ES 2

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, hbase, guava

I'm having a project using both HBase 1.0.0 (Cloudera version) and Elasticsearch. With the upgrade to ES 2.0 I'm experiencing a problem with guava version. ES 2.0 requires guava version 18.0, but Cloudera requires guava 14.0.1.

No matter what version I define in my dependency management in my parent pom one of the two won't work.

Looking around I see that this problem occurs quite some time (e.g. http://gbif.blogspot.co.at/2014/11/upgrading-our-cluster-from-cdh4-to-cdh5.html)

1) Any ideas on how to solve this problem without any complex re-design of my application?

If not, I'm thinking of doing all the ES-stuff in a separate application. Communicating via messaging (already using AMQ) for indexing. Not sure though how to communicate for search/filter requests (at the moment implemented via Java API).

2) Any other ideas?

3) Any ideas/hints on how to solve the communication issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post when googling in combination with maven-shade plug-in, so this might be another option.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade

Comment: i didn't try, but it should.. i went through with the separate service handling all the ES stuff